# The component doesn't re-render after updating the state

Tags: reactjs, rerender

```
componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(()=>{auth().get('/coordinates').then((res,err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(res);
        let labels = [];
        let parts = [];
        for(let item of res.data){
            labels.push(item.time);
            parts.push(item.numberOfParts);
        }
        let obj = this.getChartData(labels,parts);
        this.setState({chartData: obj});
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
},10000)
```

I'm updating the state after an interval of 10s, but the child component doesn't get updated with newly updated data.

I tried to use forceUpdate(), but that doesn't work either. On console logging the state after getting the new response from the API, it shows the updated content but doesn't rerender's or updates the child component.

I'm planning to update the chart(child component) on getting the new data from API.

Here is the entire code!

```
import React from 'react';
import LineChart from './Chart';
import auth from '../api/auth';

class Body extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        email:"",
        password:"",
        chartData:{}
    }
}
getChartData(label, part){
    return {
        labels: label,
        datasets:[
          {
            label:'Unix Timeline',
            data:part,
            backgroundColor:[
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
}
componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(()=>{auth().get('/coordinates').then((res,err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(res);
        let labels = [];
        let parts = [];
        for(let item of res.data){
            labels.push(item.time);
            parts.push(item.numberOfParts);
        }
        let obj = this.getChartData(labels,parts);
        this.setState({chartData:obj});
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });},10000);  
}
onFormSubmission = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let creedentials ={
        "email":`${this.state.email}`,
        "password":`${this.state.password}`
    }
    auth().post('/user/signin',creedentials)
    .then((resp, err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        this.props.signIn(resp.data.status);
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })

}
render(){
    if(!this.props.signedIn)
    return (
        <div style={{ marginTop:"10vh", display:"flex",justifyContent:"center", flexDirection:"row"}}>
            <div className="form-group shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style={{width:"400px", display:"flex", flexDirection:"column",padding:"20px"}}>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                 <input value={this.state.email} onChange={e=>{this.setState({email:e.target.value})}} type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required/>
                 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                 <input value={this.state.password} onChange={e=>{this.setState({password:e.target.value})}} type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" required></input>
                 <button onClick={this.onFormSubmission} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" style={{marginTop:"10px", alignSelf:"center"}}>Submit</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     );
    return (
        <div className="container" style={{height:"50vh"}}>
           <LineChart  chartData={this.state.chartData} legendPosition="bottom"/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Body;
```

Comment: Which chart library do you use? Can you post the chart code?

Comment: Sure! I've added it!

Comment: @kiranvj I've added the code

Comment: Are you sure if your state is getting updated, if Yes, the issue is with LineChart component. Can you post the code of LineChart

Answer (score -1):

I think your broblem is in `const obj = this.getChartData(labels,parts);`

Let replace `const` to `let`

Comment: Still, the problem persists!

Comment: Unbelievable... check my test [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/p6gncx54/2/)